# How to find top visible view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Using this type of code we can get top visible view controller in swift. But how to check same functionality for SwiftUI.

```
func getTopViewController() -> UIViewController? {
var topController: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
while topController?.presentedViewController != nil {
    topController = topController?.presentedViewController
}
return topController
```

}

Comment: This sounds a bit like an X->Y problem.  SwiftUI doesn't really work like that. What are you actually trying to achieve?